# Plot histograms from data frame based on conditions as "group_by" style

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, dplyr

I have a data frame that contains multiple columns. I am trying to plot some of these columns in function to others. First, here is an overview of the columns:

1. This should be the x-axis on my histogram, it is the number of a day within a year (01 is 1st January, 34 is 3rd February, etc)

   > head(df$day_number)
   > [1] 302  60 314  83  92  32
2. This is the decade which belongs to the day of the year you are looking at (there is a column that gives just the year)

   > head(df$decade)
   > [1] "2010-2019" "1980-1989" "1990-1999" "2000-2009" "2020-2029" "2000-2009"
3. This is the latitude of each data that relates to one day

   > head(df$lat)
   > [1] 56 62 56 57 65 58

The output that I am looking for would be a series of histograms that represents in x the day_number, in y the density of data on this day (the number of data i.e. rows that has this precise day associated), grouped by decade and latitude degree.

As an example, I would have one histogram that represents this at lat = 55 for the decade = 1950-1959, then at lat = 55 for the decade = 1960-1969, then so on, and also lat = 56 for the decade = 1950-1959, then lat = 56 for the decade = 1960-1969, etc for all my latitudes and decades.

I managed to plot the total amount of data per day_number (all decades and all latitudes merged) using this code:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=day_number)) +
  geom_histogram(color="darkblue", fill="white", bins=366) +
  xlim(0,400) +
  xlab("Day n°") + ylab("Count")
```

I had in mind that something like this should work but it does not, and I do not manage to make my idea work:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=day_number, group_by(lat = "55", decade = "1740-1749"))) +
  geom_histogram() +
  xlim(0,400) +
  xlab("Day n°") + ylab("Count")
```

I hope that someone can help with this. Do not hesitate if you need more infos. Thank you very much.

Comment: Could you please share your data using `dput(df)`?

Comment: sorry I tried to run this command but the dataset is really huge and I do not see how I can share the result of this function, the result does not make much sense to me? Can I maybe subset something that you would be missing, or add infos about class objects and so one?

Comment: You can also do `head(dput(df),20)` for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`facet_wrap()` can do that.

It looks like `lat` is currently a continuous variable. Stratifying by that would quickly get out of hand if there are many possible values, so I'd consider categorising it with `cut()` before passing it to `facet_wrap()`.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
df |> 
        mutate(lat_grp = cut(lat, breaks = c(55, 60, 66))) |> 
        ggplot(aes(day_number)) +
        geom_histogram(color="darkblue", fill="white", bins=366) +
        xlim(0,400) +
        xlab("Day n°") + ylab("Count") +
        facet_wrap(vars(decade, lat_grp))
```

Comment: Ok thank you very much I will try this, but it is important for me to keep a break of 1 latitude degree, 55, 56, 57, etc

Comment: Ok. This means having 54 histograms if you have 6 decades and 9 latitude degrees.

Comment: Yes so run it and it is almost good. Just a few more insights: 1) indeed, it is too much to be represented in one single window, is it possible to divide? 2) how do you read (66,67] in terms of what is included or not? 3) I have this warning and to be complete I would like to check what has been removed: `Warning message:
Removed 292 rows containing missing values (geom_bar).`

Comment: 1) Maybe you can first split your dataset into one dataset per latitude, and then just do `facet_wrap(~decade)`. 2) That's mathematical notation for a [half-open interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)). It might be helpful to convert `lat` into a factor before passing it to `facet_wrap()` so you just get the single number. 3) Difficult to know for sure without having your data, but likely there are 292 rows with at least an NA in `lat` or `day_number` or `decade`, so ggplot can't plot them.